# Vim: Delete from cursor to next period

Tags: vim

Is there a shortcut in vim to delete from the current cursor to the end of the sentence?

```
                                  cursor
                                    v
This is half a sentence.  My cursor is here, but I would
like to delete to this period.  I do not want to delete this part.
                             ^
                     delete from cursor to here
```

Imagine my cursor is somewhere on the text that says `My cursor is here,`.  How can I delete from this line all the way (and including) that next `.`?

Comment: I'd like to know why this got downvotes.  Not sure why this is a bad question.

Comment: Because this question shows no search-effort. This is a pretty obvious thing in Vim, and you can pretty much find it online by just typing few words in Google. Note: I didn't downvote, simply because of your reputation.

Comment: Use the built-in help and follow the links (typing `^]` follows the link under the cursor, `^T` goes back to where you where). So use `:help d` which tells you it works with `{motion}` which tells you it's documented in `motion.txt` which explains how to specify arbitrary motions to combine with `d`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though there's no exact motion for that, there are several possibilities:

1. The `)` motion deletes the remainder of the sentence, but that also includes the whitespace after the period.
2. If there were no hard line break, you could use the useful `f` motion (which only works in the current line, unless you install a plugin): `f.` This is also useful if you want to keep the period: `t.`
3. The most general motion is search via `/`. You need to search for a literal period (`\.`), and to include it, move to the end (`/e`) of it: `/\./e<Enter>`.

All of these have to be appended to the `d` "delete" command, which takes a `{motion}`.

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help` (here, `:help motion.txt` in particular); it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Answer (score 3):

you should combine d with motion command. for your example, this will be `d/\.<Ret>`

Comment: I'm very new to vim.  Can you explain how this works?  I've googled "vim motion command" but it seems more general purpose than this.  I think this says "delete" then "search to the period" and `<Ret>` executes the command.  Is that right?

Comment: this is very basic vim operation, if you have read vim help. you can type `:h motion` or `:h operator` to get more info

Answer (score 1):

This visual-mode editing may help you understand what actually happen:

```
v/\.<Ret>ld
```